# String builder to XML traverse through each node

Tags: c#, xml, stringbuilder

Hi all I am having an `XML` data which is formed in `StringBuilder` as follows

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>");
sb.Append("<TEST>"
+ "<DEMO><CONTENTINFO  name=\"Nani\" receiver=\"Lucky\""
+ "/></DEMO></TEST>");
XmlDocument XMLDocument = new XmlDocument();
XMLDocument.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
XmlNodeList nodeList = XMLDocument.FirstChild.ChildNodes;
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
}
```

I tried using `XMLDocument` to traverse through child nodes to get the data I need to split the data so that it should give `name=Nani` and `receiver=lucky` or store the key and value in a `dictionary` like `dic.Add("name","nani") and dic.Add("receiver","lucky")` . So can some one help me how to sort it out

Comment: Use XDocument. Much easier than XmlDocument

Comment: Why are you building the XML using `StringBuilder`? Why not build it directly using "LinqToXml"?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer having a strong set of class instances being formed then use the XmlSerializer and create classes to represent each of the levels of your XML structure.

```
[XmlRoot("TEST")]
public class Test
{
     [XmlElement(Name = "DEMO")]
     public Demo Demo
     {
          get;
          set;
     }
} 

public class Demo
{
    [XmlElement("CONTENTINFO")]
    public ContentInfo ContentInfo
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
}

public class ContentInfo
{
   [XmlAttribute(Name = "name")]
   public string Name
   {
      get;
      set;
   }

   [XmlAttribute(Name = "receiver")]
   public string Reciever
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
serializer.Serialize(....);
Test testInstance = serializer.Deserialize(....);

... etc.
```

The above code has not been tested but should give you the gist.

Comment: Whilst this is good advice, it doesn't explain how to pull out the attribute values on the `CONTENTINFO` element into a dictionary, and therefore doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using a `StringBuilder` to generate your XML? There are much better ways:

```
var root = new XDocument();
var test = new XElement("TEST");
var demo = new XElement("DEMO");
var contentInfo = new XElement("CONTENTINFO", 
                  new XAttribute("name", "Nani"), 
                  new XAttribute("receiver", "Lucky"));

demo.Add(contentInfo);
test.Add(demo);
root.Add(test);
```

To pull out the values you need into a dictionary you can use the following LINQ query:

```
var foo = root.Descendants("DEMO").Elements("CONTENTINFO")
              .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes())
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.ToString(), x => x.Value.ToString());
```

This will give you a dictionary looking like this:

> Key: name =
>   Value: Nani,
>
> Key: receiver = Value: Lucky